# How to check if jupyter is installed in a virtualenv programmatically in setup.py?

Tags: jupyter, python-3.7, setuptools

I want to install some python package only if `jupyter` is already installed inside the venv(virtual env) of python. How can I check it inside setup.py of my package that I am developing?

Comment: Declare `jupyter` as dependency via `install_requires=['jupyter']`. It will be installed automatically if missing.

Comment: I want to install another package if jupyter is installed else skip that package. Can this be done ?